# Understanding Time Complexity of Recursive Merge Function for Linked Lists and Comparing Recursion vs. Iteration

Tags: time-complexity

I have implemented a recursive function in Python that merges two sorted singly-linked lists. I want to confirm whether my understanding of its time complexity is correct and seek insights into the benefits of using recursion over an iterative approach.

Here's the code for the recursive function:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if(list1 is None and list2 is not None):
            return list2;
        elif(list1 is not None and list2 is None):
            return list1;
        elif(list1 is not None and list2 is not None):
            if(list1.val > list2.val):
                return ListNode(list2.val, self.mergeTwoLists(list1, list2.next));
            elif(list2.val >= list1.val):
                return ListNode(list1.val, self.mergeTwoLists(list1.next, list2));
        else:
            return None
```

My initial understanding was that the time complexity of this function is O(n), as it seems to visit each node once. However, I'm uncertain about how the recursion might affect the time complexity calculation.

I would appreciate any tips or insights into understanding the time complexity of recursive functions like this one. Additionally, I'm curious if there are any advantages to using recursion over an iterative approach in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Time Complexity:
   According to me it should be O(n+m) where n is the size of first list and m is the size of second list.
2. Benefit to doing recursion over an iterative method?

   Recursion adds clarity and reduces(sometimes) the time needed to
   write and debug code.

Note: Using recursion you are using extra stack memory but with the
Iterative approach you will not use stack memory.